# A template that accepts only pointer type arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, partial-specialization

After seeing that a template can be partially specialized for reference or pointer types, I was wondering whether I can write a template that accepts only a pointer type to start with. This is my attempt:

```
template <typename T*>
struct MyTemplate{};

int main() {
    MyTemplate<int *> c;
    (void)c;
    return 0;
}
```

This does not compile. How should it be modified? (i.e. if what I am trying to accomplish is at all possible)

Comment: Check [`std::is_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may use partial specialization:

```
template <typename T> struct MyTemplate; // Declaration

template <typename T> struct MyTemplate<T*> // Specialization
{
};
```

or use `static_assert`

```
template <typename T> struct MyTemplate
{
    static_assert(std::is_pointer<T>::value, "Expected a pointer");

    // T = value_type*
    using value_type = std::remove_pointer_t<T>;
};
```

In C++20, you might use constraint:

```
template <typename T>
requires (std::is_pointer_v<T>)
struct MyTemplate
{
};
```